# Call Microsoft Edge inside Hololens app?

Tags: hololens

Does anyone know is it possible to call or embed Microsoft Edge Window in your Hololens app? For example, I have my Spatial mesh rendered and I'm detecting the flat surfaces. I'd like to be able to call new Edge Window with predefined url whenever I tap on a flat surface. Is there any way to invoke Edge Window this way inside the app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Unity or UWP to create your app?

Comment: I'm using Unity3D. If there's no way to it with Unity, can you please give me some guides or refer where to search for solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unity, you might be able to use `Application.OpenUrl("www.google.nl");` in order to open the standard browser.

See: [Unity reference OpenURL](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html)

I am not sure if this will close your application first before opening the browser, but i hope this works for you.

If it doesnt, maybe you can try starting a new process by using: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("PathToProgram.exe");`

See: [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You cant open Edge inside your app, you can shut down your app and let the system start edge with a given URL.

If you need to get an image from a website you can use the unity www system:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html