# How to call the default browser in the Hololens app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I want to create an app that calls the Hololens default browser. I used the following code, but whenever I call this function, the Application will crash. If this code is not suitable for UWP, how can I call HoloLens' default browser in an app?

The version of the software I am using is:

1.Unity 2018 3.11f

2.Mixed Reality Toolkit v2.0.0 RC1

3.Visual Studio 2017

```
public void OpenAnlagenWiKi_URL()
{
    string tempUrl = string.Format("{0}", AnlagenWiKi_Link.text);
    Application.OpenURL(tempUrl);
}
```

I hope to successfully call HoloLens' default browser in the app.

Comment: "the application will crash", what does the exception say? And have you read the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html)?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877493/call-microsoft-edge-inside-hololens-app) you cannot Application.OpenURL() in HoloLens because it will close down the application and THEN try to open the URL.

Comment: @FredrikSchön thanks for your help ! I will try the method in the link you gave.

Comment: there is no In-App-Browser...you have to minimize your app to open the browser

Comment: @Perazim I want to use this code app to call an external browser, but each time it is used, it will directly cause the app to crash. Is there any other way?

Comment: Try Application.Quit() in InApplicationFocus or OnApplicationPause, some ppl say it minimizes the app. But I dont know how to open the browser after you minimized your app :D Maybe you can use cortana and open via her the browser with a specific url

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky. Any Hololens application is actually UWP process.

First of all, you need to switch it into the background mode by calling [AppResourceGroupInfo.StartSuspendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appresourcegroupinfo.startsuspendasync). The details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020408/minimize-uwp-programatically).

When the app would go into background, you should call open process

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i will try it.